# Programmatically update service worker if update() is not available

Tags: updates, service-worker

How can I programmatically update service worker since [`ServiceWorkerRegistration.update()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/update) has not been implemented in Chrome yet? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 6):

I assume you got this by now but I think you want [serviceWorker.skipWaiting(](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/skipWaiting))

Comment: The OP might have found their answer but it's good to have a record for someone who might search in the future. Thanks for writing this.

Answer (score 1):

From the spec.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw-test/sw.js', {scope: 'sw-test'}).then(function(registration) {
    // registration worked
    console.log('Registration succeeded.');
    button.onclick = function() {
      registration.update();
    }
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // registration failed
    console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thr best workaround seems to be to force update by changing checksum of the service worker file by some simple backend code (it can be like last commented line with microtime), which will be detected by browser

Comment: you should not rename the sw file